# Proving the differential $T_pM \rightarrow T_pR^n$ is injective when $M$ is level surface of $f$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ $(m < n)$ be a smooth function, $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ a regular value of it, and let $M = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x) = c\}$. Then $M$ can be realized as an $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ manifold via the implicit function theorem, and the inclusion map $i:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth.

> How does one show that, at any point $p \in M$, the differential map $Di_p:T_p(M) \rightarrow T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is injective?

Comment: The map is injective for any submanifold whatsoever. What is your issue?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to prove it. If $v_1 \neq v_2$ in $T_p(M)$ then they disagree on some $g \in C^\infty(M)$. But maybe this $g$ isn't of the form $f \circ i$ where $f \in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In that case, $Di_p(v_1) = Di_p(v_2)$ might be possible. I would like to rule that out by showing that every function in $C^\infty(M)$ has a lift in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but I not sure how to do that or if that's the right approach.

Comment: It might be more convenient to think of tangent spaces in terms of tangent vectors to curves, but OK, your way. Can it happen that $v(g)\ne 0$ for some $g\in C^\infty(M)$ but $v(f)=0$ for all $f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$? You're right: Use the fact that $M$ is a slice in some coordinate chart on $\Bbb R^n$ in some neighborhood of $p$ to extend $g$ by using these coordinates and a bump function.